# how to find out exactly from where print is being executed

Tags: python, printing

This application I am working on (GUI based), has well over a dozen modules. On running the application and using it, there is this particular action(clicking a label) upon which I get tons of empty prints in the stdout and because of which I suspect the application's performance is suffering. Now the problem is I am unable to find out exactly which print statement is causing this to happen.

What I have tried as yet:

- multi-buffer searches
- commented the print statements which I know will be executed and left out the one which I am almost 100% sure will never be executed. period.

What I haven't tried:

- pdb(time consuming)

Any ease hack(not too ugly) to corner out this print statement?

Comment: by "pdb (time consuming)" you mean that you don't want to learn it?

Comment: Get a debugger and set a breakpoint to the label click. Then go step by step through what's happening

Comment: @piokuc of course not. I know how to use it but being lazy to use it for this

Comment: I assumed you done the obvious thing of examining what command is associated with the clicking of the label. You should be able to determine this by looking a the GUI initialization/setup code.

Comment: @martineau that would have required a lot of code examination therefore I was avoiding it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace `sys.stdout` with a file-like that will spew out a traceback when its `write()` method is called.

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you call your printing routine, add a small unique header to printout (module name+line number) to identify the place print was initiated from.

Comment: that would work if it was only you alone who was working on the project. Secondly it would heavily clutter your stdout with useless information which you wouldn't need most of the time

Comment: @hus787 He's trying to debug, of course he's not supposed to leave such markers in production.